# Azure active directory single tenant separate webapi application access

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I have two Azure active directory applications setup.

For brevity, `App-A`, and `App-B`.

`A` is a webapp and runs on localhost while `B` is published to `somedomain.azurewebsites.net` and exposes a webapi.

Both are setup with:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions(){
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true
});

app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions{
    AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
    AutomaticChallenge = true,
    ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:ClientId"],
    Authority = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:AADInstance"] + Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:TenantId"],
    CallbackPath = Configuration["Authentication:AzureAd:CallbackPath"],                
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters{                    
        SaveSigninToken = true,
    },
    Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents{
        OnAuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailed,
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
        OnMessageReceived = OnMessageReceived,
        OnTicketReceived = OnTicketRecieved,
        OnTokenValidated = OnTokenValidated,
        OnUserInformationReceived = OnUserInformationReceived,
        OnTokenResponseReceived = OnTokenResponseRecieved,
        OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure
    }
});
```

Now `App-B` allows delegated permissions to `App-A`, and vice versa. I've also added `App-A`'s reply URL into `App-B`, `http://localhost:5000/signin-oidc`

`App-A` upon trying to access an `[Authorize]`'d controller they must sign in and are routed to the sign in page from Microsoft. Now on this sign in page, how can I immediately allow access to the `App-B` web-api from the first sign in? Can I send an access token somehow from that initial handshaking / logging in or is the proper method to make another roundtrip to collect some token similar to below?

If I need to make another roundtrip, is there an example code block somewhere that is up to date? I can't seem to get the code piece to work.

All examples I'm finding are ones like:

```
private Task OnAuthorizationCodeReceived(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context){
    var code = context.Code;
    ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
    string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
    string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(string.Format("https://login.windows.net/{0}", tenantID), new EFADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
    AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceID);
```

But I don't even see `code` being a property on the context? 
I'm using newest versions of netcore at this time.

My main goal is to make an `HttpClient` call to the `App-B` endpoint with a token retrieved somehow from the initial signing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context object has changed:

```
  context.ProtocolMessage.Code
```

The code flow will automatically store the access token in the cache which you can subsequently retrieve  using:

```
  authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync
```

Updated example using latest .netcore:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-webapi-openidconnect-aspnetcore/tree/master/WebApp-WebAPI-OpenIdConnect-DotNet

Comment: When you say the code flow will automatically store the access token in the cache, do you mean with manually retrieving by calling the line in the above block :   authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode?   Because when I tried to exclude that bit, and just use authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync, i got an error that no token was in the cache.

Comment: If you don't pass a tokencache implementation to authentication context on redeeming a code then you can't use AcquireTokenSilentAsync on subsequent request in this instance.